# Hide an ongoing notification

Tags: java, android

I have the following code to create an `ONGOING_EVENT`:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "someText" , System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Home.class), 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "someTitle", "someText", contentIntent);

notificationManager.notify(SOME_ID, notification);
```

Now, I want to kill it later on:

```
notificationManager.cancel(SOME_ID);
```

However, the notification remains. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232650/android-notification-delete this may be helpful for your porpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;`. I misinterpreted the documentation for this flag, and subsequently couldn't remove the notification. The flag usually is set by a service started with `startForeground(int id, Notification notification)` and prevents the removal of the notification until the service is stopped by `stopForeground(boolean removeNotification)`.

I now use the `startForeground`/`stopForeground` methods and the notification is shown/hidden perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented this flag yet but check the notification flag [FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL). Add this before you create the notification.

Comment: This will cancel the notification when it's clicked by the user, not what I want to achieve, as the notification details an upload.